# Socket errors running "openssl s_client -showcerts"

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a .PEM file that I want to install on a Tomcat server.  The file looks something like this:

```
friendlyName: 
subject=CN=myserver.ca.example.com, OU=servers, O=Example, C=US
issuer=CN=Example Basic Assurance Software Issuing CA G3, OU=certservers, O=Example, C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=CN=Example Basic Assurance Software Issuing CA G3, OU=certservers, O=Example, C=US
issuer=CN=Example Basic Assurance Software Root CA G2, OU=certservers, O=Example, C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=CN=Example Basic Assurance Software Root CA G2, OU=certservers, O=Example, C=US
issuer=CN=Example Basic Assurance Software Root CA G2, OU=certservers, O=Example, C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,E2EC8A310F02CA01

xxxxxxxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When I run the command "openssl s_client -showcerts -cert myserver.pem", I get this:

```
Enter pass phrase for myserver.pem:
socket: Bad file descriptor
connect:errno=9
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this when I just want to show the certificates in the file.  I've tried various options, such as -prexit, and I'm not seeing anything useful.  Do I need to extract the root certificate and install it somewhere?  If so, where?  Or is my problem something completely different?

Comment: The s_client subcommand of the openssl command line tool is for making TLS connections to a server. If you just want to see the contents of a .pem, use the x509 subcommand.